# How to allocate all of the available shared memory to a single block in CUDA?

Tags: memory, cuda, gpu

I want to allocate all the available shared memory of an SM to one block. I am doing this because I don't want multiple blocks to be assigned to the same SM. 
My GPU card has 64KB (Shared+L1) memory. In my current configuration, 48KB is assigned to the Shared memory and 16KB to the L1.
I wrote the following code to use up all of the available Shared memory.

```
   __global__ void foo()
{

  __shared__ char array[49152];
...

}
```

I have two questions:

1. How can I make sure that all of the shared memory space is used up?
2. I can increase "48K" to a much higher value(without getting any error or warning). Is there anyone who can justify this?

Thanks in advance,

Iman

Comment: when I compile with a (statically allocated) shared memory size that is too large, I get a compile error (from ptxas).  Please provide a complete compilable example of a code that has too large an allocation of shared memory, along with the command line you use to compile, for further investigation into your question #2.  If you switch to dynamic allocation of shared memory at kernel launch time as Eugene suggests, then you should get a runtime error (are you checking for errors?) if the shared memory requested is too large.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can read size of available device shared memory from `cudaDeviceProp::sharedMemPerBlock` that you can obtain by calling `cudaGetDeviceProperties`
2. You do not have to specify size of your array. Instead, you may dynamically pass size of the shared memory as 3rd kernel launch parameter.

The "clock" CUDA SDK sample illustrates how you can specify shared memory size at launch time.

Comment: If your application does not support concurrent kernel execution then you only have to allocate 1/2 * MAX_SHARED_MEMORY_PER_SM + 1 byte of shared memory to limit occupancy to 1 block per SM.